# Logstash is not processing MySQL logs correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, grok

As you can see, the message is not just the message, but also contains the date and timestamp.

[image: Valid XHTML].
[image: Valid XHTML].

This is the MySQL Log: /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
150630  9:01:29 [Warning] Access denied for user 'test1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
150630  9:03:39 [Warning] Access denied for user 'test3'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
150630  9:07:48 [Warning] Access denied for user 'test5'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
150630  9:10:00 [Warning] Access denied for user 'test7'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
150630  9:12:21 [Warning] Access denied for user 'test9'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

This is the Logstash-shipper configuration: /etc/logstash/shipper/conf.d/20-filter.conf

```
else if [type] == "mysql" {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
    match => [ "message", "%{MYSQLLOG}" ]
    overwrite => [ "message" ]
  }
}
```

This is the pattern:

```
MYSQLLOG %{NUMBER:date} %{TIME:time} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I've been trying to fix this for weeks and I actually had it working at one moment, but without intervention from my end it stopped working again. Any tips regarding debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's an extra space in your log entries between the `date` and `time` fields, so your grok isn't matching, as evidenced by the existance of the `_grokparsefailure` tag.

Try this pattern instead:

```
%{NUMBER:date}  %{TIME:time} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}] %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I've tested this in the [Grok Constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match) and it matched all the lines you provided.

Comment: Yes, it is related to the extra space. After 10:00:00 it starts working fine. I'll try this Monday, thanks!